# Unbalanced `^` and `$` anchors in Oracle regexp

Tags: regex, oracle

Why in some cases number of start-of-string anchors is not equal to number of end-of-string anchors?

```
regexp_count(chr(10)||'A'||chr(10)||'B', '^') = 2
regexp_count(chr(10)||'A'||chr(10)||'B', '$') = 1
```

---

**UPD :**
In multi-line mode disbalance has opposite direction:

```
regexp_count(chr(10)||'A'||chr(10)||'B', '^', 1, 'mn') = 1 
regexp_count(chr(10)||'A'||chr(10)||'B', '$', 1, 'mn') = 3
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/9961)

Comment: Looks like a bug. `chr(10)` followed by anything matches 2 `^` which is nonsense for a single-line mode

Comment: wow. It's like if besides this bug oracle didn't even count chr(10) as a linefeed in its regexp engine (try adding `'C' ||` before the first chr(10) the result will be 1 for both ^ and $)

Comment: Even more interesting: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/9942

Comment: Certainly looks like a bug with leading `chr(10)` being counted in single-line mode, multiple times. But @sebas, that's the [correct behaviour](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions147.htm); to get the linefeed count in that situation you'd need to use `regexp_count(str, '^', 1, 'm')` to treat it as multi-line mode. That does always seem to get the right, and balanced, counts for `^` and `$`.

Comment: @AlexPoole - You said "always"?  :-)  See my updated question.

Comment: Don't close this question.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff - I knew that would come back to bite me as soon as I'd written it *8-). But it seems to be the `n` modifier that's breaking your updated version; with just `m` it seems OK. (This is on 11.2.0.2; haven't tested any other versions but unlikely to be better on 11gR1, and it didn't exist before then. Can't see anything related on MOS).

Comment: I can confirm such behavior on 11.2.0.3.0 (IBM/AIX)

Comment: chr(10) is not returning an 'A' character. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/9995

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After investigation Oracle Support concluded that this issue is a bug.

Bug 16707134 : REGEXP_COUNT PATTERN '^' AND NEW LINE UNEXPECTED BEHAVIOR

Comment: Could you please contact Oracle Support to solve similar problem in my another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16702672/1847592)?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Sorry, but now I don't have access to Metalink . But you can ask this question on Oracle community forum https://forums.oracle.com/forums/category.jspa?categoryID=18  This forum seems to be monitored by Oracle support specialists and looks like useful place to get an authorative answer.

Comment: @ThinkJet did you check that chr(10) against V$NLS_PARAMETERS?

Comment: @AndrewWolfe Of course, no. Can you point to specific parameter(s) from `V$NLS_PARAMETERS` which can affect behavior of `regexp_count` function?