# Replacing specific substrings between tags

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, tags

I have the following HTML document fragment:

```
<ol>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some <strong>more</strong> text</li>
    <li>some more text</li>
</ol>
<ul>
    <li>even more text</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

What I would like to achieve is to replace all instances of `<li>` occurring between `<ol>` and `</ol>` with `##li##` and  `</li>` with `##/li##` whereas all instances of `<li>` and `</li>` between `<ul>` and `</ul>` should remain unchanged:

```
<ol>
    ##li##some text##/li##
    ##li##some <strong>more</strong> text##/li##
    ##li##some more text##/li##
</ol>
<ul>
    <li>even more text</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Although this is primarily a regex question, should it be of interest I am using Oracle's REGEXP_REPLACE function on Oracle XE 11g2 from within a stored procedure.

I would love to post what I have tried so far but to be honest I am completely lost on this one.

It would be OK to do this operation in two passes:

```
l_html_new :=
REGEXP_REPLACE(
  l_html_old
, '<regex1 here>'
, '##li##'
);

l_html_new :=
REGEXP_REPLACE(
  l_html_new 
, '<regex2 here>'
, '##/li##'
);
```

**Update:**

@cfqueryparam, your solution is intriguing, as it seems to do exactly what I need in JS. However, I can't get it to work in Oracle.
Here is what I have:

```
declare
  --
  c_crlf char(2) := chr(13)||chr(10);
  --
  l_html_old varchar2(4000);
  l_html_new varchar2(4000);
  l_pattern  varchar2(400);
  --
begin
  l_html_old :=   
      '<ol>'||c_crlf
  ||    '<li>some text</li>'||c_crlf
  ||    '<li>some <strong>more</strong> text</li>'||c_crlf
  ||    '<li>some more text</li>'||c_crlf
  ||  '</ol>'||c_crlf
  ||  '<ul>'||c_crlf
  ||    '<li>even more text</li>'||c_crlf
  ||    '<li>...</li>'||c_crlf
  ||  '</ul>'
  ;
  --
  l_pattern := '<(li)>(.*?)<(\/li)>([^>]*)(?=(<li>.*?<\/li>[^>]*)*(?:[^>]*<\/ol>))';
  --
  l_html_new := 
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
      l_html_old                  --source_string
    , l_pattern                   --pattern
    , '##$1##$2##$3##$4'          --replace_string
    , 1                           --position
    , 0                           --occurrence
    , 'im'                        --match_parameter
  );
  --
  dbms_output.put_line(l_html_new);
  --
end;
```

This just outputs the original string with no substitutions.
There might be an issue with the backreferences, but I don't think it is crucial. As there are no substitutions happening at all, I assume nothing is being matched.

I'll try to find out what the differences in processing are between JS and Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an ORACLE database to test with, but I can demonstrate something in javascript that you may be able to harness.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/knjv9zjp/1/

```
<(li)>(.*?)<(\/li)>([^>]*)(?=(<li>.*?<\/li>[^>]*)*(?:[^>]*<\/ol>))
```

It did occur to me that you may want to account for attributes of the LI tag, which is pretty easy.

This version will capture attributes, and put them in in the opening hash

```
<(li[^>]*)>(.*?)<(\/li)>([^>]*)(?=(<li>.*?<\/li>[^>]*)*(?:[^>]*<\/ol>))
```

This version will recognize possible existence of attributes, without capturing them

```
<(li)[^>]*>(.*?)<(\/li)>([^>]*)(?=(<li>.*?<\/li>[^>]*)*(?:[^>]*<\/ol>))
```

Comment: @silentsurfer sqlfiddle is down atm but I will try to help more when it is back up.

Comment: thanks, I really appreciate you helping me out here.

Comment: @silentsurfer Try `<(li)>(.*?)<(\/li)>([^>]*)((<li>.*?<\/li>[^>]*)*(?:[^>]*<\/ol>))` and your replace string is `##$1##$2##$3##$4$5` Oracle regex appears not to support lookarounds. I am afraid this may replace only the first iteration though.

Comment: I've stumbled across this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702672/why-non-greedy-quantifier-sometimes-doesnt-work-in-oracle-regex) indicating a bug regarding the greediness of operators in Oracle. Do you think this might be an issue here?

Comment: @silentsurfer That's an interesting read! I'll poke things with sticks and brackets when fiddle rises from the dead.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is simple Replace():

```
SELECT REPLACE(
'<ol>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some <strong>more</strong> text</li>
  <li>some more text</li>
</ol>
<ul>
  <li>even more text</li>
  <li>...</li>
 </ul>', '<li>', '###li###')
FROM dual
/
```

Output:

```
<ol>
   ###li###some text</li>
   ###li###some <strong>more</strong> text</li>
   ###li###some more text</li>
</ol>
<ul>
   ###li###even more text</li>
   ###li###...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: He specifically doesn't want the `<li>`s within a `<ul>` modified.