# Non-greedy Oracle SQL regexp_replace

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm having some issues dealing with the non-greedy regex operator in Oracle.

This seems to work:

```
select regexp_replace('abcc', '^ab.*?c', 'Z') from dual;
-- output: Zc (does not show greedy behavior)
```

while this does not:

```
select regexp_replace('abc:"123", def:"456", hji="789", dasdjaoijdsa', '(^.*def:")(.*?)(".*$)', '\2') from dual;
-- output: 456", hji="789 (shows greedy behavior)
--         I would expect 456 as output.
```

Is there something glaringly obvious that I may be missing here?

Thanks

Comment: What output do you actually want in the second case?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: updated OP.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a non-greedy regular expression in `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         'abc:"123", def:"456", hji="789", dasdjaoijdsa', -- input
         'def:"(.*?)"',                                   -- pattern
         1,                                               -- start character
         1,                                               -- occurrence
         NULL,                                            -- flags
         1                                                -- capture group
       ) AS def
FROM   DUAL;
```

**Results**:

```
| DEF |
|-----|
| 456 |
```

If you want to skip escaped quotation marks then you can use:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         'abc:"123", def:"456\"Test\"", hji="789", dasdjaoijdsa',
         'def:"((\\"|[^"])*)"',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS def
FROM   DUAL;
```

**Results**:

```
|         DEF |
|-------------|
| 456\"Test\" |
```

**Update**:

You can get your query to work by making the first wild-card match non-greedy:

```
select regexp_replace(
         'abc:"123", def:"456", hji="789", dasdjaoijdsa',
         '(^.*?def:")(.*?)(".*$)',
         '\2'
       ) AS def
FROM   DUAL;
```

**Results**:

```
| DEF |
|-----|
| 456 |
```

Comment: But can you explain what is happening in the OP?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just like your answer, no. `DUMP()` reveals no untoward characters in their input and there is no obvious reason why `REGEXP_REPLACE` would fail but `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with a similar non-greedy pattern would succeed.

Comment: Upvoted...perhaps replace is the wrong tool for this anyway.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Found a solution - just make the first wildcard match non-greedy.

Comment: @MT0: THAT WORKED! What's the reasoning?

Comment: I don't know why - I guess that there is some sort of feature (or bug) to the regular expression that means the regular expression parser for `.*` will go past the `def:"` match looking (greedily) for the furthest match and then will start backtracking but somehow fails to backtrack the second `"` match as well - but it is only a guess.

Comment: @MT0 Random question: Are you testing on actual Oracle, or a demo site like Rextester?  I ask because I used Rextester, and this site has known bugs (in addition to any bugs which the underlying database may have).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, on Oracle, [SQLFiddle on an Oracle 11gR2 instance](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/106) or [Oracle Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/index.html).

Comment: It's a bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16756711/130758

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly why your regex replace is failing, but I can offer a version of your query which is working:

```
select
    regexp_replace('abc:"123", def:"456", hji="789", dasdjaoijdsa',
                   '^(.*def:")([^"]*).*',
                   '\2') from dual
```

The only explanation I have is that lazy dot isn't working, at least not in the context of the capture group.  When I switch `([^"]*)` above to `(.*?)`, the query will fail.

### Demo

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I know that "hack". Unfortunately not always will it work (think of cases when what's inside the quotes can have escaped quotes, for instance. I was really wondering if this was an Oracle bug or if I may have been missing something blatantly obvious.

Comment: @devouredelysium My suggestion most certainly is not a "hack" and in fact is the only option for regex flavors which don't support the Perl lazy dot.  If you have nested quotes, then regex isn't even the right tool for what you need.  In that case, you should look into using a parser.